# Deep learning toolbox

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, deep-learning

I am getting the following error when using the [deeplearntoolbox](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox). specifically, When executing the file `test_example_DBN.m`

```
??? Error: File: nneval.m Line: 18 Column: 17
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

Error in ==> nntrain at 66
        loss = nneval(nn, loss, train_x, train_y);

Error in ==> test_example_DBN at 38
nn = nntrain(nn, train_x, train_y, opts);
```

Comment: You should provide more details.

Comment: i am testing the deeplearntoolbox but the problem is that the test code provided doesn't work properly. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: We don't know either. So at least provide the file content so we can help you, or get in touch with the deeplearntoolbox support or the author of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of left parenthesis is not equal to the number of right parenthesis in your `nneval.m Line: 18.`. You may look into the code by clicking this error message, and count the number of left parentheses and right parentheses on the line of code.

**EDIT**

I checked out the `nneval.m` file from [github](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox/blob/master/NN/nneval.m). What's your Matlab version? Try to change line 18 to :

```
[er_train, tmp]               = nntest(nn, train_x, train_y);
```

If your input has 6 argument, change line 22 as well:

```
[er_val, tmp2]             = nntest(nn, val_x, val_y);
```

The error message should be eliminated.

Comment: Thank you lennon310.I think the problem was the matlab version. I am using matlab 7.6.0 R2008b. After changing the code it works now.

Comment: you are very welcome. You may consider accept the answer if your question is solved, so others that face the similar problem will have a reference. Thanks